# How to update an azure pipeline variable from a powershell task?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

How do I update a pipeline variable in an azure task?
[image]

I'm currently thinking og using the Azure cli to do this:

1. Login to az
2. use az `pipelines variable update --name=AppVersion --value=7.13.1` command to update

I also tried updating the variable without the AZ CLI but could not get the `$AppVersion` to update properly. Is it possible to update the `$AppVersion` in a task without the AZ CLI?
I tried a powershell script:

```
Write-Host $(AppVersion) # 18.13.0
$AppVersion = "9.0.0"
##vso[task.setvariable variable=AppVersion;isOutput=true]9.0.0
$env:AppVersion = '9.0.0'
Write-Host $(AppVersion)  # Still 18.13.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To use powershell to create/update an Azure DevOps variable, the syntax will look as follows:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AppVersion]9.0.0"
```

or

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AppVersion]9.0.0"
```

Two things to note when updating a variable in this way:

- The variable will only be updated on subsequent tasks, not the current task that has defined it.
- updating in this way will only update the `AppVersion` variable for the current job. Subsequent jobs will not be aware of the variable update. This can be achieved by using `;IsOutput=true`, and redefining the variable within that job or stage.

  - Read in [Microsoft docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) on how to achieve it, they have a good example.

Taking the above notes into account, here is the values of AppVersion in an example yaml:

```
jobs:
- job: Job1
  steps:
  - powershell: | 
      Write-Host "AppVersion is: $(AppVersion)"                       # Appversion = 7.13.0
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AppVersion]9.0.0"
      Write-Host "AppVersion is: $(AppVersion)"                       # Appversion = 7.13.0

  - powershell: |    
      Write-Host $(AppVersion)                                        # Appversion = 9.0.0
      
- job: Job2
  steps:
  - powershell: | 
      Write-Host "AppVersion is: $(AppVersion)"                       # Appversion = 7.13.0
```

---

Depending on how you determine if `AppVersion` should be updated or not, you can achieve a global update of `AppVersion` by updating it underneath `variables:` in your yaml file:

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual') }}:    
    AppVersion: 9.0.0 # will default to pipeline value of 7.13.0 if build reason is not equal to Manual.
```

Comment: That only updates the variable for a local scope in my script. It won't change an Azure Pipeline variable.

Comment: HI @JorgeZuverza , I have updated my answer to hopefully provide you with more information to the scope of the variable update.